# How do i draw triangles between the points of a fibonacci sphere?

Tags: lua, mesh, fibonacci

I create the points using this function right here.

```
local GR = (math.sqrt(5) + 1) / 2
local GA = (2 - GR) * (2 * math.pi)

local function fibonacciSpiralSphere(num_points)
    local vectors = {}

    for i = 1, num_points do
        local lat = math.asin(-1 + 2 * i / (num_points + 1))
        local lon = GA * i

        local x = math.cos(lon) * math.cos(lat)
        local y = math.sin(lon) * math.cos(lat)
        local z = math.sin(lat)

        table.insert(vectors, Vector3.new(x, y, z))
    end

    return vectors
end
```

How the points turn out.
[image: 1]

I just can't figure out how to make a sphere mesh out of them.

Answer (score 5):

Things like that are usually solved using [Delaunay Triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation).

As you have some knowledge about your point set you can simply find each points nearest neighbours. So run through the point set and check the distances.

Comment: I think you're mistaking this for some kind of research-service. I can only point you into a direction. please do not expect me to write on-demand tutorials or summarize resources for you so you don't have to read them. I gave you plenty of information to start with. what stops you from carefully reading the linked Wikipedia article? or just searching the web for "surface delauny sphere"?  https://fsu.digital.flvc.org/islandora/object/fsu:182663/datastream/PDF/view